# Android programming. choosing number

Tags: android, user-interface

it is hard to search for what i want because i have no idea what it is called so i do not know how exactly to ask this.

[image]

i want to make the user to choose numbers just like this in my application.

for example i put 3 of those and i set a certain number of values for each (for example from 0 to 22 in the first, from 5 to 40 in the second and 0 to 60 in third). and later the user chooses his values and when submitting the app reacts considering his choices.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

That widget that you're looking for is called a 'Number Picker' and you can find more info about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

Answer (score 1):

Android has a native implementation for a widget like this, it's called `NumberPicker`.

However, it was added alongside API 11 (3.0 or Honeycomb). So it might give you trouble if you want to support older Android versions. As an aternative, [this library](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) will help you if you're planning to support older APIs, it has been tested and confirmed working down to API 7 (2.1 or Eclair).

As a bonus, you could also give [BetterPicker](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) library a shot - it supports many kind of beautiful and customizable pickers.